# convert sql query to hibernate query to retun list of specific object

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, converters

I 'd like to convert the query below to hql to return me a `List<Article>` because with createSqlQuery it is impossible , I must convert the result manually  :
here is the sql query :

```
Query query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(
                 "select * 
                  from article 
                  where articleID in (select articleID 
                                      from article_depot 
                                      where depotID = "+depotID+")"
              );
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a **OneToMany** relation between `article_depot` and `article` (One Depot contains multiple articles) if this have been correctly mapped the query would be :

```
Query query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT d.article from article_depot d where d.depotId = :depotId");
query.setParameter("depotId", depotId);
List<article> resultList = query.getResultList();
```